# Upload the dropped file inside Read DropZone to SharePoint online document library inside SPFX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spfx, pnp-js

I am building an SPFx web part inside our SharePoint Online tenant, where we have a react dropzone, to upload a file, which should automatically get uploaded to SharePoint document library:-

Here is my Service:-

```
// Uploads a dropped excel sheet to the site assets library
  public uploadExcel = async (name:string, file: ArrayBuffer): Promise<string> => {
    try {
      alert("1");
      const fileAddResult = await this.dmsWeb.lists
        .getByTitle(this.folderIconListTitle)
        .rootFolder.files.addUsingPath(name,file, { Overwrite: true });

      return fileAddResult.data.ServerRelativeUrl;
    } catch (ex) {
      const result = (ex as Error).message;
      console.log(result);
      Dialog.alert(result);
    }
  };
```

Here is my markup :-

```
 public render(): React.ReactElement<ICategoriesPanelProps> {
    const appearingStyle = mergeStyles(AnimationStyles.scaleDownIn100);

//code goes here

<Stack tokens={{ childrenGap: 15 }}>
        <Stack.Item>
            <DropzoneExport
              themeVariant={this.props.themeVariant}
              onDrop={this.onDrop}
              uploadPlaceholders={this.state.uploadPlaceholders}
              removeDocument={this.removeDocument}
            />
```

here is the onDrop method:-

```
  private onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    try{
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {

      const reader = new FileReader()

      reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
      reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
      reader.onload = async () => {
          // get file content
          const binaryStr = reader.result
          this.props.uploadExcel("Category", binaryStr);
         
    }}}
    catch(e)
    {const result = (e as Error).message;
      alert(result);}
  };
```

Currently i am getting this error:-

> Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'ArrayBuffer'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> 'ArrayBuffer'.

on `this.props.uploadExcel("Category", binaryStr);`. any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`FileReader.result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) can be either a `string` or an `ArrayBuffer` (in typescript terms, it is `string | ArrayBuffer`, i.e. "string or ArrayBuffer"). Your function `uploadExcel` is declared to accept only `ArrayBuffer` as a parameter.

You may need to use some type casting. The easiest way (if you are sure, that binaryStr *actually* contains ArrayBuffer and not a string):

```
this.props.uploadExcel("Category", binaryStr as ArrayBuffer);
```

Other than that, it looks like you need to actually **read** the file (i.e. call one of the [read methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) of the `FileReader`, like `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)`. Now, the variable 'file' seems to be unused.